# How do I get a download link for an object I upload to an AWS bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using AWS S3 `boto3` to upload files to my AWS bucket called `uploadtesting`. Here is an example implementation:

```
import boto3

...

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('files/report.pdf', 'uploadtesting', 'report.pdf')
```

Accessing the object from the AWS S3 console allows you to see the object URL, however it is not a downloadable link. What I wanted to know is how can I use python to print out a downloadable link to the file I just uploaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are asking how to generate a URL that allows a **private object** to be downloaded.

This can be done by generating an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides access to a private S3 object for a limited time.

Basically, using credentials that have access to the object, you can create a URL that is 'signed'. When Amazon S3 receives this URL, it verifies the signature and provides access to the object if the expiry period has not ended.

From [Presigned URLs — Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html):

```py
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': object_name},
                                                    ExpiresIn=expiration)
```

The `ExpiresIn` parameter is expressed in seconds.

Comment: Is there a way I can automatically do this with `boto3` in python and then generate the download link?

Comment: Nevermind, I'll take a look at this first https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url

Answer (score 2):

The format is:

```
https://BUCKET-NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/OBJECT-KEY
```

So your object would be:

```
https://uploadtesting.s3.amazonaws.com/report.pdf
```

There is no supplied function to generate this string, so use:

```
url = f'https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{key}'
```

Comment: I accessed a link like that from the S3 console under "Object URL", which brought me to an access denied page. I wanted to know how to use python to automatically print out a download link like that after I upload the file.

Comment: I have added another Answer for this version of your question.